# How do you display data in a table using two join tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join, html-table

How do you display data in a table using two join tables in codeigniter

I want to display both the student table and parent table data in the table view. I have used the parent id as the foreign key for two tables.

I used this code but it doesn't work properly.

This is my model

```
function fetch_data()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student As st LEFT JOIN parent As pt ON st.p_id =pt.p_id";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result();


    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

}

This is my controller

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Tableview_model');


    $student_data= $this->Tableview_model->fetch_data();
    $data["student_data"]  =  $student_data;

    $parent_data=$this->Tableview_model->fetch_data();
    $data["parent_data"]  =  $parent_data;

    $this->load->view('register_students', $data);


}
```

This is the view

```
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if( !empty($student_data && $parent_data ) ) 
        {
        foreach ($student_data AS $student) {


        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $student->student_code; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student->f_name; ?> <?php echo $student->l_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student->tel; ?></td>

            <?php
            }

        ?>
            <td></td>

            <?php
            foreach ($parent_data AS $parent) {
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $parent->f_name; ?> <?php echo $parent->l_name; ?></td>
            <?php
            }

             ?>
        </tr>
        <?php 

            }
        ?>

    </tbody>
```

[image]

but the output is wrong I get parent first name and last name for student f name and l name. and the parent field doesnt show properly

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work properly."

Comment: I just added the output in the question. the thing is im getting a wrong output.

Comment: Please use join queries in Codeigniter, refer it, especially JOin methods

Comment: Can you please refer the Codeigniter documentation, which will explains you correctly

Comment: have I used it in the wrong way in my function?

Comment: Yes, there are only some simple errors, please try to find out and get expertise, :)

Comment: but actual issue is related to tr and td... isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know why are you splinting data into 2 different arrays and loops, you are already using `JOIN` for both tables, you can achieve your target as:

```
<?php
foreach ($student_data AS $student) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $student->student_code; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $student->f_name; ?> <?php echo $student->l_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $student->tel; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $student->tel; ?></td>
<?php
if(isset($student->f_name) && isset($student->l_name)){ // using isset() because of LEFT JOIN
?>
<td><?php echo $student->f_name; ?> <?php echo $student->l_name; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

You are already getting all information from your query here:

```
$data["student_data"]  =  $student_data;
```

So, no need to run your query twice, when you are using `JOIN` in your query. this is unnecessary:

```
$parent_data=$this->Tableview_model->fetch_data();
$data["parent_data"]  =  $parent_data;
```

**Issue in Your Code / Explanation:**

Ist `foreach()` using `<tr>`, it will repeat until `foreach` end. but second `foreach()` using `<td>`, it will repeat until `foreach` end, and this will increase `<td>` not `<tr>`.

I simple words, you are repeating columns not rows, if you use your loop at once, this issue will be resolved.

**Side Note:** Instead of raw query, you need to use [CI join method](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html). something like:

```
// using last param as 'left' for LEFT JOIN.
$this->db->join('parent pt', 'st.p_id = pt.p_id', 'left');
```

Comment: Because I want to get 'parent first name and parent last name' in the last column (parent) not student

Comment: you can acheive by using 1 loop, no need to use twice

Comment: Thank you. I'll use that for JOINS.  Is it right if  I use if(isset($parent_data->f_name) ... since I want parent data.

Comment: Oh Thank you now  I get it :D

Comment: actually u are using LEFT JOIN, for suppose, if you dont have parent name, then code will not break. @deeva

Comment: thats good. @deeva

Comment: Thank you so much this really helps :)